# Unsigned Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore assembly. Is there a signed version?

Tags: windows-runtime, assemblies, mvvmcross, binaries

All of the other binaries downloaded seemed to have been strong-named except Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.dll.  Can anybody shed light on this? Was this an oversight?  Is there a signed version (vNext) that I can download somewhere?

Comment: Maybe asking on their github repository? https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross

Answer (score 0):

> All of the other binaries downloaded seemed to have been strong-named except Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsStore.dll

Currently, no - MvvmCross does not strong name its WindowsStore assemblies.

In fact, currently only 2 out of the 100+ MvvmCross projects do sign their outputs.

Users seem to have very strong opinions on whether assemblies should not be signed. If you have requirements for strong names then please do register your arguments/requirements on issues like https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/232 (or a new request) - but please do include your arguments/reasons for needing strong named assemblies